# Why are the errors not being displayed on the template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Referencing http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html

I have a route `checkout.address` which renders `app/templates/checkout/address.hbs`. It has the following:

1. Two kinds of forms
2. One form to allow the user to create a new
   address
3. A form for each existing address so the user can edit any of
   them

When I try to create or update an address, with invalid values. The app complains since the API returns validation errors. Which is expected. The `Network` tab in Ember-Inspector confirms that the API returned errors in the form of:

```
errors: Object
  street: Array
    0: can't be blank
```

However, the errors are not displayed on either form. I would have expected the line below to do that:

```
{{#each error in errors.street}}
  <br />{{error.message}}
{{/each}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
// app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('checkout', function() {
    this.route('address');
  });
});

export default Router;

// app/controllers/checkout/address.js
import Ember from 'ember';

// export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    create: function() {
      var _this = this;

      // this.get('model').save().then(function(address){
      this.store.createRecord('address', {
        street: this.get('street')
      }).save().then(function(address){
      // address.save().then(function(address){
        _this.transitionToRoute('addresses.index', address);
      }, function(errors) {
        // console.log(errors);
        // Need this promise, so we can render errors, if any, in the form
        // console.log('error');
      });
    },

    update: function(address) {
      var _this = this;

      address.set("street", address.get('street'));

      address.save().then(function(){
        _this.transitionToRoute('checkout.address');
      }, function() {
        console.log('here');
        // Need this promise, so we can render errors, if any, in the form
      });

      return false;
    }
  }
});

// app/templates/checkout/address.hbs
<h1>Addresses</h1>

<p>Create address:</p>

<form {{action "create" on="submit"}}>
  <p>
    <label>Street:
      {{input value=street placeholder="Foo street"}}
    </label>

    {{#each error in errors.street}}
      <br />{{error.message}}
    {{/each}}
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>

<ul>
  {{#each model}}
  <li>
    Address: {{street}}

    <form {{action "update" this on="submit"}}>
        <label>street:
          {{input value=street placeholder="Foo Street"}}
        </label>

        {{#each error in errors.street}}
          <br />{{error.message}}
        {{/each}}
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: hmm - it should work then... can you throw it into a jsbin?

Comment: I think this is the problem. The `create` action doesn't operate with the model hook from the route. So doing `{{#each error in model.errors.street}}` or `{{#each error in errors.street}}` doesn't do anything in the template

Answer (score 0):

First, which adapter are you using? DS.Errors works be default in the ActiveRecordsAdapter. If you're using the RESTAdapter, you have to inmplement it first.

I think you need to set the errors as a property on your controller. Try doing:

```
this.set('errors',errors);
```

In the errors handler for the promise returned by the save.